# C# Datagrid placed on page dynamically need to remove columns before it is placed

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have very dynamic code that is build and added to a page (so no DataGrid code exists on the page until after I build it and add it to the page using a line of code like this:

```
PlaceholderToUse.Controls.Add(DataGrid1);
```

This process works great as is, but now I have a need to group the data and change the colors for each grouping of the data to make it visually easy to see/group together.  I want to do something similar to this link:  http://aspalliance.com/723_Enhancing_the_DataGrid_with_Grouped_Rows_and_Subheadings.all

Since I am adding the DataGrid dynamically I was unable to get this to work (may be I just dont understand how to do it when adding it dynamically).  If anyone has a way to do the above after adding a DataGrid dynamically to the page please let me know.

Otherwise I came up with another solution that I am trying to get working similar to the above.

I have 4 columns in my DataGrid:

- `GroupingTitle`: this is the header I want around/above each section of the DataGrid
- `GroupingCSS`: this is just a HTML color  that I want the background to be changed to for these rows.
- Then 2 data points

I am able to have the colors applied (and I should be able to get the header added as well) but once I do that I do not want these 2 extra  columns (`GroupingTitle` and `GroupingCSS` to display in the DataGrid/on the page as I only need them for the formatting). The issue I am having is I can not remove these 2 columns from the DataGrid.

I have tried various versions of: `DataGrid1.Columns.Remove` or `RemoveAt` and when stepping through the code the 2 columns appear to be removed from the DataGrid but still show up on the screen (and yes they are removed before I call `PlacoldertoUse.Controls.Add(DataGrid1)`).

I think I am just missing something or not calling the correct piece of code to remove the columns the right way. I'm showing the code that is taking the dynamic datagrid (that is built in previous steps) here below. It has a lot of commented out code for the different things I was trying to do to remove the columns after I have the colors applied using the columns I noted above. This code has the color coding being applied correctly right now (I did not work on the headers yet).

There are probably other ways to do this but I do not want to rewrite how I am doing the dynamic DataGrid as I am using this in many other areas of my code as it would cause me to have to rewrite huge sections of code that are working great and make it less dynamic as well I beleive.

```
private DataGrid WorkingTestForAddingHeaders(DataGrid DataGrid1)
{
    bool IsContainHeadersToRemove = false;

    foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in DataGrid1.Items)
    {
        // cell header is the first column for the row and if we set the Item.CssClass (it sets the entire row to that style)

        // have to make sure there is enough cells first before trying to do the code
        if (dataGridItem.Cells.Count >= 2)
        { 
            // to see if the column grouping is filled in and background color is populated
            if (dataGridItem.Cells[0].Text != "" && dataGridItem.Cells[1].Text != "")
            {
                // set flag to remove these columns below
                IsContainHeadersToRemove = true;
                dataGridItem.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", dataGridItem.Cells[1].Text);
            }
        }

        //dataGridItem.CssClass = "VMReportBG";
        //dataGridItem.Style.Add("background", "pink");
    } // end foreach

    // if the datagrid contains the columns we don't want anymore, remove them.
    if (IsContainHeadersToRemove)
    {
        //DataGrid1.Columns.Remove(DataGrid1.Columns[0]);

        // find better way to do this and use col names!
        // now remove the extra rows with the colors and headers
        // removing by the index, starting with first one then other one
        //DataGrid1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
        //DataGrid1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        // this removes them but still displayed so must remove them after it is displayed or something?
        //DataGrid1.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
        //DataGrid1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        //DataGrid1.Columns.Remove(DataGrid1.Columns[1]);
        //DataGrid1.Columns.Remove(DataGrid1.Columns[0]);

        // try getting the data out of the GRID, then remove the columns, then set it back??
    }

    return DataGrid1;
}// testing dataGrid
```

Any help would be appreciated